# How to switch 7 wires with a single on/off slide switch

Tags: switches, switching

I am working on a project, where I want to build a raspberry pi into a nintendo 64 console, and be able to switch between with a single switch. By that I mean, I want to be able to use a single slide switch to either switch on the raspberry, or the n64.

I already figured the most stuff out, but I need help with wiring the controller port.

I have a n64 to USB controller adapter, which is connected to the raspberry. Each controller has 3 pins, VIN, GND and Data. I have 2 ports I need to switch. I also need to switch the usb Power for the raspberry.

So, I need a single switch, which has 2 states (ON, OFF), to switch the n64 controller ports to either the n64 console, or to my USB adapter. It also needs to switch the 2 wire power for the raspberry. I made some pictures to visualize it better:

So here is how it should be for to work with the regular N64. The controller ports are wired to the n64 console, and the raspberry power is not connected.

[image]

Then, when you switch it over to work with the raspberry, the n64 controller ports should go to the USB adapter, and the raspberry power is connected.

[image]

Now, my problem is I don't know how to achieve that. I know there are slide switches with enough pins, but they have multiple possibilities, not only two.

I also need something small, since the n64 case is small and doesn't have a lot of space.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you need a 7PDT switch.  Not sure they exist.

Comment: thoughts: 1) you may not need to switch the power lines, just the data lines. You might need diodes to ensure that you don't back-power the other device. 2) you almost certainly don't need to switch the grounds. 3) watch out with your switch, because it won't respect the connection order. Look inside a USB connector, you'll see that the power pins are longer than the data pins, so they make contact first.

Comment: @tomnexus So a 3PDT switch with diodes on the 3.3V lines for the controllers? I'll just try it and see if it works

Comment: They'll need to be schottkey diodes, at 3.3 V you can't afford to lose a whole 0.7 V. Why not have the raspberry pi control a bank of relays, as many as you need, to switch Vcc and data? The slide switch would be an input to the Pi.

Comment: I may not be fully understanding the issue, but I don't think a multi-pole switch is necessary.  Power and ground can be connected to both the N64 and the USB adapter with a splitter.  Data can be split as well if the bus can handle the extra stub length.  Maybe use a buffer to avoid that.  That leaves a single switch to power the raspberry pi.  Some advice: Were I doing this project, I'd power the Pi all the time, and use the switch to indicate whether I wanted the N64 on or not.  I could then put FETs at the controller ports to switch the power and data lines to either the Pi or the console.

Answer (score 5):

N-pole switches, for more than a few N, are usually rotary switches. For example, you could take the switch out of a commercial 2-way serial port  or VGA port switch box, which will have at least 8 or 9 poles. You might even have one of these lying around somewhere — I know I do.

---

Here a stack of various switches I found laying around the office:

[image: photo 1]

Opening the one second from the top, I found the following switch. It has 16 poles, but only 9 are used.

[image: photo 2]

Comment: Is your Telex still working too? I haven't seen any of those boxes since the late 90s.

Comment: @Transistor: Well, yes they are old. But then the N64 is late-90s technology, too, so this is completely appropriate! Anyone who has one is likely to have the other...

Comment: I don't think I can go this route, I have very limited space inside the case, so it's gotta be something small